# RegEx replace wrong symbols C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I need to replace wrong symbols except chars and digits in my string with dash character "-"

```
var myString = "this=is+/* wrong!@# string^&*(";
```

I use

```
Regex.Replace(myString, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "-");
```

and as a result it's "this-is----wrong----string----"

but I need "this-is-wrong-string"

What should I change in my RegEx. Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Expresso gives the correct output.  Did you do something else before running the `Replace` ?

Comment: Tried this with expresso. I get {this-is-wrong-string-} as output, which seems to be correct given your regex.

Comment: I have tried your sample code and the result is as you require with a single dash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unable to reproduce:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var input = "this=is+/* wrong!@# string^&*(";
        var output = Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9A-Za-z]+", "-");
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }                   
}
```

Output: `this-is-wrong-string-`

So you may want to use `TrimEnd('-')` to get rid of the trailing "-", but otherwise it looks fine to me. Compare your code with my short but complete program, and if you can't find what's wrong, come up with a similar short but complete program which *demonstrates* the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex works for me:

```
PS> "this=is+/* wrong!@# string^&*(" -replace '[^0-9a-zA-Z]+','-'
this-is-wrong-string-
```

But you need to remove trailing `-` afterwards.